# How to get a raw key value from in Yesod's Persistent?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

Having an entity, such as `User`, I can retrieve it's type-safe key using `entityKey`, which gets me `Key User`. How can I retrieve the raw value of the key, for example as an `Int64`? There used to be functions for that in the early versions of *persistent*, such as [`fromPersistKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-0.1.0/docs/Database-Persist.html#v:fromPersistKey) and `showPersistentKey`, but they're not available any more.

Comment: it's moved into the backend part - see [fromSqlKey](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.4/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#fromSqlKey)

Comment: @Carsten do you want to make that an answer so Petr can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this functionality was moved into the backend-part of the framework

for SQL it would be [`fromSqlKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.4/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#fromSqlKey)

and there is indeed a [type class - `ToBackendKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.4/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#t:ToBackendKey) for it so just look for those in you used persistent-backend and you should find the function (it does not have to be an `Int64` everywhere - in MongoDB there seems to be quite a [few helpers though](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-mongoDB-2.1.4/docs/Database-Persist-MongoDB.html))